# Haskell can't deduce type?

Tags: haskell

I've tried countless google searches for an answer but being pretty new to Haskell, I didn't understand half the things I found and the other half just didn't quite relate.

My problem is this, if I run these statements in ghci

```
Prelude> let x = 5 :: (Num a) => a
Prelude> sqrt x
```

I get what I expect

```
2.23606797749979
```

But, if I put this in a file and compile (granted what I'm doing here is pretty trivial)

```
sqrtNum :: (Num a, Floating b) => a -> b
sqrtNum x = sqrt x
```

I get this

```
myfile.hs:2:18:
    Could not deduce (a ~ b)
    from the context (Num a, Floating b)
      bound by the type signature for
                 sqrtNum :: (Num a, Floating b) => a -> b
      at test2.hs:1:12-40
      `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for sqrtNum :: (Num a, Floating b) => a -> b
          at test2.hs:1:12
      `b' is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for sqrtNum :: (Num a, Floating b) => a -> b
          at test2.hs:1:12
    Relevant bindings include
      x :: a (bound at test2.hs:2:9)
      sqrtNum :: a -> b (bound at test2.hs:2:1)
    In the first argument of `sqrt', namely `x'
    In the expression: sqrt x
```

The problem's probably very simple and I'm just overseeing it (as such are my experiences with every other error I encounter) but this one just isn't clicking.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your type claims you can convert from one type of number `a` to another type `b`. But `sqrt` doesn't do that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you're saying is you have a function going from Num a to Floating b.  The sqrt function requires a Floating type as input, but you are only guaranteeing Num.  Here's the type of sqrt:

```
Main> :t sqrt
sqrt :: Floating a => a -> a
```

So, let's copy sqrt and make this a ftn from Floating to Floating:

```
sqrtNum :: (Num a, Floating a) => a -> a
sqrtNum x = sqrt x
```

I left the Num, although only Floating is required.  [Floating is a Fractional, and Fractional is a Num.](http://haddocks.fpcomplete.com/fp/7.8/20140916-162/haskell2010/Prelude.html#t:Fractional)

Answer (score 3):

If that wasn't clear enough, let's peek "under the hood". Type classes are a form of syntactic sugar where Haskell stores a library of functions at the type level.  Typeclass constraints can therefore be implemented simply as extra arguments which get passed along implicitly. For example if I write:

```
class Truthy a where
    truthy :: a -> Bool

instance Truthy Integer where
    truthy = (== 0)

instance Truthy Bool where
    truthy = id
```

then we could define a function like:

```
maybeTruthy :: Truthy x => x -> Maybe x
maybeTruthy x | truthy x  = Just x
              | otherwise = Nothing
```

The key here is that what I am doing is exactly the same as this slightly more convoluted piece of code:

```
data Truthifier x = Truthifier {truthify :: x -> Bool}

boolTruthifier :: Truthifier Bool
boolTruthifier = Truthifier id

integerTruthifier :: Truthifier Integer
integerTruthifier = Truthifier (== 0)

maybeTruthified :: Truthifier x -> x -> Maybe x
maybeTruthified lib x | truthify lib x = Just x
                      | otherwise      = Nothing
```

The only difference is that Haskell has effectively bound, e.g., `boolTruthifier` to the `Bool` type, so that I do not need to pass it explicitly to `maybeTruthy` because it "comes along for the ride" via the type `Bool` of the argument to the function. Above I could easily define `notTruthifier = Truthifier not` and I could start doing things with `maybeTruthified notTruthifier` instead of `maybeTruthified boolTruthifier`.

This explains, for example, why Haskell by default forbids `instance (Num a) => Truthy a`, and you have to instead write `newtype TruthNum x = TruthNum x` and then `instance (Num a) => Truthy (TruthNum a)`: Haskell has to have a top-level type to register that function library with; if you give it `(Num a) => Truthy a` then it has no better place to put it than on `a` -- that is, on all functions -- whereas in the latter case it puts it directly on the `TruthNum` type and only uses it when the `x` also has a dictionary for the `Num` functions.

How `sqrt` fits into all of this: in GHCi you will find out that the type of `sqrt` is:

```
Prelude> :t sqrt
sqrt :: Floating a => a -> a
```

In other words, `sqrt` can be done on a value of any type, if that type has the `Floating` dictionary defined for it. Its `sqrt` returns a value **of the same type**, since the signature is `a -> a`.

You tried to write `(Num a, Floating b) => a -> b`. This is a more permissive type than what the definition actually allows.